# String class split method

Tags: java, arrays, string, multithreading

I have written one java thread to split string

```
public void run() {

String input="Sasi|maran|rishabh";

String arr[]=input.split("|");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        try{

            System.out.println(arr[i]);

            Thread.sleep(1000);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

output expectation:

```
sasi
rishabh
maran
```

But what output i am getting :

```
S
a
s
i
|
m
a
r
a
n
|
r
i
s
h
a
b
h
```

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for `String.split` *very carefully*, and consider what `|` means in regular expressions...

Comment: Both answers below do not seem to deal explain how OP wants  "rishabh" to print before "maran" when they are not reordering arr[] at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String#split method takes regex as an argument. `|` is a meta character, and it's have a special meaning in regex. Just escape it.

```
String arr[]=input.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the pipe `|` like:     `String[] arr = input.split("\\|");`
and do `System.out.print(element);` instead of  `System.out.println(arr[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
 input.split("\\|")
```